# "Looking for a job" contains missing or expired job[s]

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I've noticed lately at least a couple of jobs featured in my "Looking for a job" sidebar box link through to invalid/expired/missing jobs. For example, I currently have this link:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/56053/devops-engineer-aws-puppet-atlassian?a=iNvB2PS2Wtz&utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=jobs-small-sidebar-blue-looking

Which shows a page saying

> Job Not Found
>
> Sorry, we couldn’t locate that job listing. It might have expired or
>   been removed.
>
> If you feel something is missing that should be here, please contact
>   us.

as at 28th January 2015.

Is this just a caching issue - perhaps jobs have been removed recently and the ads haven't refreshed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yikes! We had to manually update some jobs a couple of weeks ago due to an unrelated bug, and forgot to update their ad campaigns accordingly.

The issue has been identified and fixed, there shouldn't be any dead links anymore.

Thanks for the heads up <3